# Garbage Collector Kicking in too early (possibly) while still executing low level c++ code

Tags: c#, managed-c++

I get a strange intermittent crash in my c++ code because my managed c++ class is being deleted by GarbageCollector (possibly). I can see destructor being called before DoingSomeLowLevelStuff is completed. Adding an empty call at the end of the function fixes the issue but I am not sure why GC is kicking in at all as 'WManagedClass c' is still in the scope.

DoingSomeLowLevelStuff function take a bit of time to complete (few seconds) as it does several network calls.

C#:

```
void func()
{
   WManagedClass c = new WManagedClass();

   DataSet x = c->DoingSomeLowLevelStuff(); //intermittent crash in there

   //do some stuff with x here

   //adding this line fixes it

   c->DoNothing(); //empty call in WManagedClass
}
```

Actually I should have pointed out that func gets calls from the return of a background worker threads.

```
BackgroundWorker bg_C = new BackgroundWorker(); 
bg_C.DoWork += (sender, args) => //called to do work in background 
{ 
}; 
bg_C.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) => 
{ 
func(); 
}; 
bg_C.RunWorkerAsync();
```

And here is the managed c++ including DoingSOmeLowLevelStuff

```
public ref class WManagedClass
{
protected :

    !WManagedClass()
    {
        if (pLowLevelClass)
            delete pLowLevelClass;
        pLowLevelClass = NULL;
    }

public :

    CLowLevelClass* pLowLevelClass;
    WManagedClass()
    {
        WSADATA wsaData;
        short wVersionRequested;

        wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 0);
        if (WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData) != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup failed.");
            return;
        }

        pLowLevelClass = new CLowLevelClass();
    }
    ~WManagedClass()
    {
        this->!WManagedClass();
    }

void DoNothing()
{
}
    DataSet^ DoingSomeLowLevelStuff()
    { 
        CDpDataSet* pDS = pLowLevelClass->DoingSomeLowLevelStuff();
        DataSet^ ds = nullptr;
        if (pDS) 
        {
            pDS->Name = "name";
            ds = ConvertDataSet(pDS);
            delete pDS;
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the code of `DoingSomeLowLevelStuff ` ? If it is synchronous, C# should wait for the result in which case it can't be GC'd.

Comment: Agreed, I am guessing that `DoingSomeLowLevelStuff` is async under the hood freeing up the main function to complete and be collected.

Comment: We do expect c# to wait for result. Thing to note. I am using VisualStudio 2010. Also DoingSomeLowLevelStuff is a managed c++ wrapper that calls c++ and it has a lot of code including a lot of network calls.

Comment: Actually I should have pointed out that func gets calls from the return of a background worker threads.   


BackgroundWorker bg_C = new BackgroundWorker();
bg_C.DoWork += (sender, args) =>  //called to do work in background
{

};

bg_C.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
{
 func();
};
bg_C.RunWorkerAsync();

Comment: @Sheepcookers please edit that information into your question.

Comment: Can background worker thread make it an async call?

Comment: This is normal for the posted snippet, .NET uses an aggressive collector and if it can't see the class object in use halfway through a method then it can collect that object.  It has no such powers for unmanaged objects like CLowLevelClass nor knowledge that WManagedObject's finalizer has nasty side-effects.  Ideally you fix this in WManagedClass but you didn't post enough code.  Simply adding GC::KeepAlive(c) is the I-know-how-it-works alternative over DoNothing().

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. So GC.KeepAlive(c) and c.Dispose when done? So where do I clean up c++ object if not finalizer? So if I didn't put clean up code in the finalizer then my WManagedClass would have been garbage collected and then resurrected when c.DoingSomeLowLevelStuff() returned with a DataSet?

Comment: Good thing you mention Dispose().  You really, really need to google "c++/cli stack semantics".  The correct way to write this code, solves the problem as well.